# C# MongoDbDriver - Unset, Cannot make it unset field in database

Tags: c#, mongodb, migration, unset

I'm trying to find the way to make this work.
Documentation of the MongoDbDriver is pretty poor, and just a couple of "solutions" found by google.

I need to remove the field from the database through C# migration script.

```
var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(person => person.Id, personId);
var update = Builders<Person>.Update.Unset(person => person.Address.PostalCode);
collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

This is what I found as a solution on the net, but this doesn't work. Field is still in the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: [Unset seems to take a string argument](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_UpdateBuilder_Unset.htm) which should hold the name of the field to be removed from the document. So I expect Unset should be called like `Unset("SomeParent.FieldToRemove")`

Comment: Tried that too. Not working either...

Comment: What does your MyEntityType look like then?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean?

Comment: MyEntity does have a propery named "SomeParent" and it has a type with a property "FieldToRemove". It doesn't have attributes that changes its naming and there is not an extra level to consider? For example: in your code you have `e.SomeParent.FieldToRemove`. it is unclear where `e` comes from. There is no reason why this doesn't work so it must be something on your end that is different from what you show here. See if you can extend the example code into a proper [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited the code. But still I don't know why isn't working. As you said, there is no reason not to work... I tried with just string also not working. I know it's something on my end, but I just cannot see it

Answer (score 0):

Just checked, your above query works as expected, see results below before and after:

before updating:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.p.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616ace670b6d6703634faf70"), "Address" : { "PostalCode" : "200" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616ace660b6d6703634faf6f"), "Address" : { "PostalCode" : "100" } }
```

after updating by personId = ObjectId("616ace660b6d6703634faf6f")

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.p.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616ace670b6d6703634faf70"), "Address" : { "PostalCode" : "200" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616ace660b6d6703634faf6f"), "Address" : {  } }
```